# JDBC Derby JPA Persistence testing issue "Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered 'USER'"

Tags: java, testing, derby, jboss-arquillian

I have an entity class called `User` and when I do persistence testing with Arquillian I have always have an error...

> `Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 13.`

...because of the class name "`User`". I assume `User` is the reserved keyword. When I change my entity name to `User_` it works fine.

Do I have to change my entity name? Is there anything else I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [`USER`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj42476.html) is a built-in function in Derby. You'd have to specify a different table name for the JPA entity (usually done via the @Table annotation).